# NSTableView: make total width of all columns always be the width of the visible portion of the table

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, interface-builder, nstableview

I have a NSTableView with 2 columns. I'd like to know if there is a way to make it so that the right edge of the right column is always on the right edge of the clip view (so that it never goes beyond the clip view and horizontal scrolling isn't enabled), yet maintaining the ability to resize the two columns by moving the separator between them. This is essentially the same behavior as a split view.

I know IB offers options to control the resizing of columns, but I can't seem to enforce the rule that the total width of the two columns must be the width of the clip view (the visible portion of the table).

Comment: How the table should be affected while resized superview less than the sum of your columns' minimal width?

Comment: @Astoria The columns have no minimal width (or it is very small, like 2 points), and the rest of the laout ensures the width of the table is never smaller than a certain amount, say 200 points.